# Confusion over Datatable's sort direction arrows

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

I feel like I'm seeing discrepancies in Flutter's `DataTable` sort order arrows between Material Design and Flutter's implementation.

Material Design's [Data table spec](https://material.io/design/components/data-tables.html) (mostly) shows the arrow pointing up when the column data ascends and the arrow pointing down when the column data descends. This is true in the sorting section and the specs section. There is one image regarding tooltips where it's the opposite. The text never actually specifies the direction, however.

[image]

In Flutter though, it appears to be the opposite. Ascending data has a downward pointing arrow and descending data has an upward pointing arrow. I have found this to be true in both my own implementation and the [official Flutter `DataTable` demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/data_table_demo.dart), image seen below:

[image]

To me personally, it makes more sense that ascending data has the arrow pointing up, but I'm trying to understand if there is a design bug in Flutter or if I'm simply misunderstanding Material Design or making too many assumptions from pictures.

I think part of my confusion is described in [this article about sort order arrow direction](https://hackernoon.com/sorting-arrow-confusion-in-data-tables-5a3117698fdf), especially their point near the end of the article about how a triangle is interpreted vs. an arrow.

Is Flutter correct with their sort order arrow directions?

Comment: IMHO this is just wrong. Pointing down means descending (obviously) and pointing up ascending. Maybe it is just an accident. The words imply that ascending is *upwards* and vise versa..

Comment: Having the arrow relate to ascending vs descending can be confusing if some columns are ascending by default while others descend. Most users don't actually think that far into it, so I went with the less visually noisy down arrow as the default sort order, and up arrow to mean reverse. It's probably safe to say the material spec supersedes the flutter demo however.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with my app while using setState from a date selection widget, which would cause the arrow in the first column of my data table widget to go from "up" to "down" without changing the sort order.

[image]

I accessed the DataTable source code in my project and added an extra condition to the if statement at the top, which fixed the bug and did not affect any of the other functionality:

Location

```
flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/data_table.dart
```

Original Code [Starting at line 1142]

```
if ((_up != newUp) && !skipArrow) {
  if (_orientationController.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
    _orientationController.forward();
  } else {
    _orientationController.reverse();
  }
}
```

Bug Fix

```
if ((_up != newUp) && (newUp == false || _up != null) && !skipArrow) {
  if (_orientationController.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
    _orientationController.forward();
  } else {
    _orientationController.reverse();
  }
}
```